# How can I mimic the output of syntax macros (\marg, \oarg, etc.) without using the ltxdoc class?

Tags: listings, verbatim

I have come to realize that the pleasant style (argument in italics, enclosed by angle brackets) of macro descriptions in numerous package documentations is actually produced by a number of special commands, such as `\marg` and `\oarg`, provided by the `ltxdoc` document class.

The following screenshot is taken from documentation of the `listings` package.

[image]

How can I produce the same (or similar) result with normal packages (e.g. `listings`) in, say, the `article` document class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plundering existing code goes a long way `:)`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for typewriter braces 
\usepackage{textcomp}    % for ``text'' angle brackets
\usepackage{xcolor}

% adapted from doc.dtx    
\providecommand\meta[1]{\textlangle{\itshape #1\/}\textrangle}

% directly taken from ltxdoc.dtx
\providecommand\marg[1]{%
  {\ttfamily\char`\{}\meta{#1}{\ttfamily\char`\}}}
\providecommand\oarg[1]{%
  {\ttfamily[}\meta{#1}{\ttfamily]}}

% directly taken from listings.dtx (lstdoc.sty)
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\def\rstyle{\color{darkgreen}}

% adapted from listings.dtx (lstdoc.sty)
\providecommand\rcmdname[1]{\texttt{\rstyle\string#1}}

\begin{document}
\rcmdname\lstset\marg{key=value list}
\par
\rcmdname\lstinputlisting\oarg{key=value list}\marg{file name}
\end{document}
```

References:

- http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/base/doc.dtx
- http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/base/ltxdoc.dtx
- http://www.ie.u-ryukyu.ac.jp/~e105704/parallel/tex_parallel/listings/lstdoc.sty

Comment: Thanks, :-) This works just fine. Although I cannot completely understand the code. But I will firstly search for what I do not know by myself. Moreover, I have found an easier solution provided by @LeoLiu (but not on SE site): Use `listings` package, and set `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,moredelim=[s][\normalfont\itshape]{<}{>}}`.