# Writing code in a different style

Tags: overleaf, code

I want to write code in LaTeX with this style [image] I tried with listings but I didn't get the same result. Does anyone could hepl me?

Comment: You should use `\texttt{}` or `\ttfamily` to switch to typewriter font. As for listing, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33039/using-ttfamily-with-bfseries-or-how-to-enable-bold-in-fixed-width-font

Comment: I found the answer to my question in another question jaja https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174793/how-can-i-mimic-the-output-of-syntax-macros-marg-oarg-etc-without-using-t

Comment: Enjoy typesetting with LaTeX!